# Let y be a polynomial in p^1/n with rational coefficients.prove that in all polynomials y,y^2,y^3...y^n ,each term occurs in atleast 2 polynomials.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The above problem is part of a broader question that any polynomial with rational coefficients in p^1/n is the root of an equation of degree n with rational coefficients.proving the above leads to a proof of this, but I seem to be stuck.

Comment: Well, any element of $\mathbb{Q}[p^{1/n}]$ can be written as $y=a_0+a_1p^{1/n}+...+a_{n-1}p^{(n-1)/n}$. This is because larger powers $p^{M/n}$ can always be reduced $M=nq+r$ with $0\leq r<n$. Now, powers of $y$ can be written in the same form. So the equations for $y,y^2,...,y^n$ give you $n$ equations in $1,p^{1/n},p^{2/n},...,p^{(n-1)/n}$. So, you can solve for $1$ as a function of the rational coefficients and the $y,y^2,...,y^{n}$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply- but I still have a doubt...what if a term of the form a*p^k/n occurs in only one of the polynomials y,y^2,...y^n?then won't any polynomial with rational coefficients of the form ay+by^2....ly^n always equal to a rational term + the above irrational term as it cannot be cancelled out?